# Mac OS X - System Preference Pane won't open

Tags: cocoa, macos, system

I'm working on a System Preferences Pane. It opens fine on some computers, but on other Macs (all running 10.5.5), the preference pane refuses to load and simply hangs, spitting the following into the console:

```
11/9/08 8:38:50 PM [0x0-0x31031].com.apple.systempreferences[369] Sun Nov 9 20:38:50 Macintosh.local System Preferences[369] <Error>: Failed to create window context device 
11/9/08 8:38:50 PM [0x0-0x31031].com.apple.systempreferences[369] Sun Nov 9 20:38:50 Macintosh.local System Preferences[369] <Error>: CGWindowContextCreate: failed to create context delegate.
11/9/08 8:38:55 PM [0x0-0x31031].com.apple.systempreferences[369] Sun Nov 9 20:38:55 Macintosh.local System Preferences[369] <Error>: Failed to create window context device
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It might be very possible that a preference file associated with the particular system preference pane is corrupted.

You can try removing the associated preference file, with the System Preferences closed, from your user ~/Library/Preferences/ folder and restarting your machine. Usually for Apple System preferences that file would be ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this particular pref pane doesn't read or write to any prefs files. I did a full refactor on it and the problem went away. Oh well!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I always post answers that I have just incase for archiving the answers and other people might have the problem.

Normally when you have an Account Prefpane not loading error it's usually because 2 Guest accounts reside on the computer. First go to Macintosh HD (or the root HDD name is) and go to the Users folder. Check in here and see if you have more than one guest account. Then make sure you aren't logged into any of the guest accounts, open up terminal and type:

sudo dscl . -delete /users/guest1

That should delete the other user account and try to open the account prefpane then.